# Merge two differently-formatted XML files with XSLT by matching id

Tags: xml, xslt

One of my XMLs is like this:

```
<people>
    <person code="111" name="Bob" />
    <person code="222" name="Sue" />
</people>
```

And the other is like this:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <id>111</id>
        <age>80</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>222</id>
        <age>73</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

The "code" from the first file is the same as the "id" from the second file.

I would like to merge these two to get this:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <id>111</id>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>80</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>222</id>
        <name>Sue</name>
        <age>73</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

How can I do this with XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first person files have all person ids you care about, you can do something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="person">
        <person>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
            </id>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </name>
            <xsl:for-each select="document('ip2.xml')//person[id=current()/@code]">
                <xsl:apply-templates  />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </person>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="id" />
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates    />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <id>111</id>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>80</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>222</id>
        <name>Sue</name>
        <age>73</age>
    </person>
</people>
```